# Aggregate separate Flume streams in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, flume, spark-streaming, rsyslog

I am researching the ability to do some "realtime" logprocessing in our setup and I have a question on how to proceed.

So the current setup (or as we intend to do it) is as follow:

- Server A generates logfiles through Rsyslog to a folder per customer.
- Server B generates logfiles through Rsyslog to a folder per customer.

Both server A and B generate up to 15 logfiles (1 per customer) in a folder per customer, the structure looks like this:

```
/var/log/CUSTOMER/logfile.log
```

On server C we have a Flume sink running that listens to Rsyslog tcp messages from server A and server B. Currently for testing we only have 1 flume sink for 1 customer, but I think we will need 1 flume sink per customer.

This Flume sink then forwards these loglines to a Spark application that should aggregate the results per customer.

Now my question is: how can I make sure that Spark (streaming) will aggregate the results per customer? So let's say each customer will have it's own Flume sink, so how can I make sure Spark aggregates each flume stream separately and doesn't mix 2 or more Flume streams together?

Or is Kafka more suitable for this kind of scenario?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: How many customers do you plan on having? How important is event availability? What are you doing with this data? In order to make an architectural suggestion, you really need to understand both tools and your application extremely well.

Comment: About 15 customers at the moment, they can (and will increase). Event availability: should be able to resent after connection lost. Data will be inserted into a database for displaying in an application.

Comment: How quickly do you need your results? How many *consumers* will you have?

Comment: If it were me, I would use Kafka to manage the events and Storm for real-time analytics.

Comment: Kafka has really nice queuing features you may want to look into. Here's a really good walk-through on [Kafka and Spark Streaming](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2014/10/01/kafka-spark-streaming-integration-example-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kafka with customer id as partition key. So basic idea in Kafka is that a message can have both key and value. Now kafka guarantees that all the messages for same key go to same partition (Spark streaming understands concept  of partitions in Kafka and lets you have have separate node handling every partition), If you want you can use flume's kafka sink to write messages to Kafka.